# Displaying markers in a certain radius in Android

Tags: android, json, google-maps, google-maps-markers, android-volley

I am making an app that uses maps api. I have a bunch of markers on the server. What I want to do is ***display only the markers in the certain radius of user's current location*** (for example, show all markers in a 10 kilometer radius from my current location).

MapFragment:

```
if (myLocation != null) {
    latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();
    longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();
}

MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(
        new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_me));

mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
        .target(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).zoom(12).build();
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
        .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(final LatLng arg0) {

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + String.valueOf(arg0.latitude) + "," + String.valueOf(arg0.longitude) + "&key=myKey";

        // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray jObj = new JSONObject(response).getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("address_components");

                            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SetRestaurantActivity.class);

                            for (int i = 0; i < jObj.length(); i++) {
                                String componentName = new JSONObject(jObj.getString(i)).getJSONArray("types").getString(0);
                                if (componentName.equals("postal_code") || componentName.equals("locality") || componentName.equals("street_number") || componentName.equals("route")
                                        || componentName.equals("neighborhood") || componentName.equals("sublocality") || componentName.equals("administrative_area_level_2")
                                        || componentName.equals("administrative_area_level_1") || componentName.equals("country")) {
                                    intent.putExtra(componentName, new JSONObject(jObj.getString(i)).getString("short_name"));
                                }
                            }

                            intent.putExtra("latitude", arg0.latitude);
                            intent.putExtra("longitude", arg0.longitude);

                            startActivity(intent);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                int x = 1;
            }
        });
        queue.add(stringRequest);

    }
});
```

MyRestaurantsFragment:

```
public class RestaurantsFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = RestaurantsFragment.class.getSimpleName();

// Restaurants json url
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private List<Restaurant> restaurantList = new ArrayList<>();
private ListView listView;
private CustomListAdapter adapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                     ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_restaurants, container, false);

listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.restaurants_list);
adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), restaurantList);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
pDialog.show();

SQLiteHandler db = new SQLiteHandler(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();
final String userId = user.get("uid");

StringRequest restaurantReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
        AppConfig.URL_GET_RESTAURANT, new Response.Listener<String>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());
        try {
            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
            boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

            if (!error) {
                JSONArray restaurants = jObj.getJSONArray("restaurant");

                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                hidePDialog();

                // Parsing json
                for (int i = 0; i < restaurants.length(); i++) {
                    try {

                        JSONObject obj = restaurants.getJSONObject(i);
                        Restaurant restaurant = new Restaurant();
                        restaurant.setUserName(obj.getString("name"));
                        if (obj.getString("image") != null && !obj.getString("image").isEmpty()) {
                            restaurant.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                        }
                        restaurant.setLat(obj.getString("latitude"));
                        restaurant.setLon(obj.getString("longitude"));
                        restaurant.setDate(obj.getString("restaurant_name"));
                        restaurant.setTime(obj.getString("restaurant_description"));

                        // adding restaurant to restaurant array
                        restaurantList.add(restaurant);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

                // notifying list adapter about data changes
                // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                // Error. Get the error message
                String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // JSON error
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SphericalUtils` method `computeDistanceBetween()` from [google-maps-utils](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils) to calculate distance from your position to every restaurant and filter out its collection by calculated distance

```
    ...
    restaurant.setDate(obj.getString("restaurant_name"));
    restaurant.setTime(obj.getString("restaurant_description"));
    restaurant.setLat(obj.getString("latitude"));
    restaurant.setLon(obj.getString("longitude"));
    // adding restaurant to restaurant array
    if (SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(new LatLng(restaurant.getLat(), restaurant.getLon()), userLatLng)<10)
       restaurantList.add(restaurant);
    }
```